# problem with limit of functions sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Consider 
$$f_n\left(x\right)\:=\:\sin ^n\left(x\right).$$
How to check what are the points that this sequence is  converges pointwise in these domains:

1. $\left[\frac{-\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}\right]$
2. $\left[0,b\right]\:\text{for}\:\frac{\pi \:}{2}>b>0$
3. $\left[0, \frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

So far, I see for 1) that if $x=1$ than it converges pointwise to $1$. But from here I struggle... Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1$, When $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $f_n(x) \to 1$.

When $x=\frac{-\pi}{2}$, $f_n(x)=\left(-1\right)^n$, which doesn't have a limit.

For rest other values of $x$, $-1\lt sin(x) \lt 1$, and hence $f_n(x) \to 0$. Similarly you can analyse for the rest of the cases.

Comment: i see in the graph that if −1<fn(x)<1, and hence fn(x)→0, but how to prove that if -pi/2 < x < 0 then fnx-->0 ?

Comment: when $\frac{-\pi}{2} \lt x \lt 0$, $-1 \lt sinx \lt 0$

Comment: and you know that $lim(x^n)$ when $n \to \infty$, goes to $0$ if $|x| \lt 1$